# ag-Grid to mimic Excel with Angular 9 material components

Tags: excel, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm building a web app with an Angular 9 front end (Typescript) and Django with SQLite back end. The main purpose of the app is data entry and database management. I'm using material components to build various forms within mat steppers. It's no problem building the forms and sending data to the back end when using the material components as is, but for one of the steps, I would like to implement a grid entry that has all the following:

1. Copy/paste feature directly from Excel
2. Calculated fields in each row based on the pasted data
3. Drop down fields where the options are pulled from the current data

For example, I'd like the ability to have a grid where, for each row, some columns are populated by choosing an option from a drop down, some are populated by pasting in directly from excel, and some are populated as calculations using the pasted data + other columns. All this data should then be pushed to the back end and stored in the database upon a button click.

All of this would be one step within a larger form.

Is all of this actually possible with the ag-grid community version? Additionally, are there any other packages that would help pull this off? It doesn't look too likely based on my research, but I'm still new to Angular, ag-grid etc.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything as I understand my requirements might be a bit confusing.

Comment: You would require a lot of customization to make ag-grid work like excel. For the features you are looking for you would need enterprise features for clipboard functionality. tldr; I wouldnt recommend if you are looking to mimic excel in the long run

Comment: I agree with @Pratik_Bhat - having worked with ag-grid enterprise for a couple of years now, and customizing it heavily with an eye towards making it as Excel-like as possible, I think that it would be very difficult and time-consuming (but not necessarily impossible) to achieve what you describe, even with the enterprise version. I think it would be impossible with the community version.

Comment: Thanks for the response y'all. I thought it may be unrealistic as it is a lot to tackle especially with my current (nonexistent) background with ag-grid.